# displaying long crosshair on screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Is there any way to display long cross-hair? (not just a crosshair for mouse icon).
I need this for studying & correlating values on 2 graphs (arranged one below the other).

(On Windows, I found this http://www.mlin.net/CrossHair.shtml)

Thanks,

Vineet

Comment: You could always paste both graphs into an image in `gimp` and correlate there.

Comment: Thanks. But copy-pasting images in gimp for every graph (I have hundreds of graphs) is a pain in XXX. That's why I am looking for a cross-hair. Anyway, thanks for you comment.